# Duplicate entries in admin view due to M2M field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
  organizations = models.ManyToManyField(Organization)
  facilities = models.ManyToManyField(Facility)

class Organization(models.Model):
  ..fields here

class Facility(models.Model):
  ..fields here
```

Whenever I enter multiple entries for organization the user value is duplicated that many times in the admin view list, but not for facility.

Comment: show us how you enter multiple entries for organization and facility. the code.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve duplication entries issue, modify your admin class "list_display" attribute to show the desired fields in the admin list view.

Customize get_organizations and get_facilities methods according to your requirements, replacing 'name' with the actual field you want to display for the Organization and Facility models.